# Is it possible to build two child modules at the same time using Maven 3.1?

Tags: maven, module, parent-child, parent

We're using Maven 3.1.1.  I have a project with multiple modules

```
    <modules>
            <module>module-A</module>
            <module>module-B</module>
    ...
            <module>module-E</module>
            <module>module-F</module>
</modules>
```

modules "modlue-E" and "module-F" do not depend on one another.  Normally when we want to build our project, we run "mvn clean install" on the parent pom.  To speed up our build, is it possible to still run "mvn clean install" on the parent but have the two modules, "E" and "F", build at the same time (concurrently)?  They should still run after modules A through D complete.

Trying to speed up our build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven3 has an experimental feature of concurrent builds

You can read about it in more detail [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Parallel+builds+in+Maven+3)

It practically enables you to specify the number of threads per build

`mvn -T 4 clean install # Builds with 4 threads`

But there is one thing that you must keep in mind is that the whole concept of maven multi module project is to bind dependant projects into a single build pom from where they can built  and deployed following a strict build sequence ( project A is to be built before project B etc ). So if you are demanding parallel build of some projects, that sort of beats the whole concept of sequential build of a multi-module project.

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect this had an answer but that seems to have sped things up a lot.  One thing I had to do in my maven-compiler plugin was set the "fork" flag to "true", otherwise I was getting all these crazy compilation errors.